# Lagom: How to use topics without Event Sourcing

Tags: scala, akka, lagom

I am new to Lagom and I want to deal with Event Sourcing at some later point. So I'm  not using the persistentEntityRegistry, instead I'm using a simple repository for CRUD operations.
Anyway I would like to have the ability to notify other Services, when a create operation has happened.
In the hello-lagom project the topic is implemented like this:

```
override def greetingsTopic(): Topic[GreetingMessage] =
  TopicProducer.singleStreamWithOffset {
    fromOffset =>
      persistentEntityRegistry.eventStream(HelloEventTag.INSTANCE, fromOffset)
        .map(ev => (convertEvent(ev), ev.offset))
  }
```

This will obviously not work, when I'm not working without the event sourcing, so I just wondered if there is another way to publish events to the topic.
I'm thinking about sth. like this:

```
override def createSth = ServiceCall { createCommandData =>
    val id = UUID.randomUUID()
    repository.addSth(Sth(id, createCommandData.someValue)) map {createdItem =>
        myTopic.publish(SthWasCreated(id))
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the kafka client directly? It is plainly simple

Comment: I haven't seen any point at the documentation, which describes how to implement the method, which returns the Topic with the Kafkaclient directly

Comment: I mean use the kafka client directly instead of relying on lagom message broker api. 
IMHO, I dont think it is straight forward to do what you wish to do. message broker api, is for event sourcing to transfer messages from the write side to read side (which is via kafka currently)

Comment: I don't know if it is used for the event sourcing as well, but it is used for asynchronous inter service communication

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no guarantee with your code that the event will be published to Kafka. If there is a failure after the item is added to the repository but before it is published to Kafka, that update will be lost. This is the reason Lagom's message broker API builds on event sourcing: to guarantee that the message will be eventually published, even on failure.